# Ubuntu Bottom Edge

Tags: ubuntu-touch, application-development

So Canonical always presents the "great" Bottom Edge feature of Ubuntu Touch but how do we actually implement it? Do we have to implement it ourselves? I have not found any information about it in the APIs.
SO how do we do it ?

Comment: If you mean the bottom tab that you can slide to view, than it is included in the default template when you create an Ubuntu template in Qt Creator.

Comment: And what is the actual name of this component ?

Comment: lol I have no idea ;D